# How to change product attribute's scope in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, scope

My issue is simple :

- We have a bunch of product attributes with wrong scopes

They are defined as `Global` and we want their scope should be `Website`.

How to handle this programmatically?

For example with the product attribute `price`

I know how to create an attribute with the scope that I want. But I don't know if and how to update an existing scope attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to these articles. They might help you-

[Programatically update a single attribute in Store View Scope](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90000/programatically-update-a-single-attribute-in-store-view-scope)

[How to update the attribute scope programmatically in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311444/how-to-update-the-attribute-scope-programmatically-in-magento-2)

Thanks,
Rashi